# Do I have to complete the Fire Lord subplot in the same term as I got it in Atelier Escha & Logy?

Tags: atelier-escha-and-logy

Until this term I was able to complete all bonus assignments (the outer ring) in Atelier Escha & Logy. However, with the frequent tracks to the Searing Wastes I'm afraid I'll run out of time if I complete the Fire Lord subplot and will not be able to do all the tasks from the outer assignment ring.

Do I need to complete the Fire Lord thing in the same term as I got it? (term 6, I think…)

Comment: And then everything changed when the Fire Nation attacked!

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have to complete the bonus assignments in the term they're given.  I had the same issue, and was worrying I couldn't complete all the assignments in the time frame.

When you move onto the next term, you won't get to complete the current ones, **but**, the very last term is special.  It lasts a year, and opens up all your other term assignments for you to complete.  So if you don't get it done now, you'll get another chance before the game completes.

Comment: I think i might not have worded my question well. My current intent was to leave the Fire Lord for later while you suggest that I leave the minor assignments for later. Do you want to tell me that a) you are able to clear up all the missed minor tasks later or b) that you can postpone building and improving the airship for a bit?

Comment: If you don't complete your main assignment, the game will end.  It's been a while since I've played, though, so I wasn't sure if the Fire Lord is a main assignment or a bonus one.  You can leave bonus ones.  You can't leave the main one.